# Rename Email attachments with Python (2.7.5)

Tags: python, email, attachment

I'm looking for a simple solution to rename attachments within emails. (I've stored ~11k CSV files in customer emails and want to rename those)

```
import getpass, imaplib, email, smtplib
...
for item in email_body:
    m = email.message_from_string(item)
    mail_date =  m['date']
    mail_subject =  m['subject']

    if m.get_content_maintype() != 'multipart':
        continue

    for part in m.walk():
        if part.get_content_maintype() == 'multipart':
            continue
        if part.get('Content-Disposition') is None:
            continue
    # the filename
    filename=part.get_filename()

    # my attachment
    payload = part.get_payload(decode=True)
```

Here I stuck. I thought there is a method that is called part.set_filename or something like that, but I cant find it.

Here is an abstract from the mail:

```
----next32sdfsdfsdg827463sbc
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=HU014_W1345.CSV
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=HU014_W1345.CSV
```

I tested something like this:

```
print part['Content-Disposition']
```

contains the filename:

```
attachment; filename=HU002_W1342.CSV
```

How to change it?

Comment: Are you sure the last 5 lines are indented correctly?

Comment: Yes, works fine. I dont know why, but it works ;)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same task and this is how I solved it:

```py
part.set_param("filename", your-new-filename, header= 'Content-Disposition')
```

#your-new-filename to include its file extension
#Old post, but hope this helps someone!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).